# converting a integer to a string

Tags: c

I have used rand function to generate a random number. I want to collect this number to a `char buffer[10]` or to a `char *ptr`

```
main()
{
    char *ptr;
    int a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    a = rand();
}
```

I want to copy the value in a to a buffer or point it by `char *ptr`, please help me out in this

Comment: [_itoa()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for reference, here's how to use `snprintf` when you don't know in advance how big the buffer needs to be:

```
size_t len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", a) + 1;
char *ptr = malloc(len);
if (!ptr) {
    // memory allocation failed, you must decide how to handle the error
} else {
    snprintf(ptr, len, "%d", a);

    ... // some time later

    free(ptr);
}
```

However, since your code is written in an old style (no return type for `main` and all variables declared at the start of the function), it may be that your C implementation doesn't have `snprintf`. Beware that Microsoft's `_snprintf` is not a direct substitute: when it truncates the output it doesn't tell you how much data there is to write.

In this case you can use the value `RAND_MAX` to work out how many digits the value might have, and hence how big your buffer needs to be. 10 is not sufficient on Linux, where `RAND_MAX` is `2147483647`, and so you need 11 bytes for your nul-terminated string.

Btw, I've neglected the possibility of `snprintf` indicating an error other than truncation, which it does with the return value -1. That's because `%d` can't fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
char x[10];
sprintf(x, "%d", integer_number);
```

Comment: Please use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: @Petriuc Florin: Hi,if i want to use char *ptr, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
char ptr[10];
sprintf(ptr,"%d",a);
```

If you want to use `char *ptr`

```
char *ptr = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
sprintf(ptr,"%d",a);

// And If you want to free allocated space for ptr some where:
free(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to use `snprintf()`.

```
int answer = 42;
char buf[32];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", answer);
printf("The answer is: %s\n", buf);
```

If you want to use a dynamically allocated buffer:

```
const size_t size = 32;
char *buf = malloc(size);
if (buf != NULL) {
    snprintf(buf, size, "%d", answer);
}
```

Comment: "Safer" to use `snprintf` without checking the return value, only if truncating the output is a less dangerous bug than buffer overrun. Which in this case, to be fair, it is, because `rand()` doesn't guarantee a uniform distribution anyway, so who cares if you further bias it by truncating some values? In general, using length-limited string functions without checking for truncation is extremely dangerous and can (albeit less frequently) lead to security flaws just as bad as the ones caused by buffer overruns.

Comment: @SteveJessop "The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() write at most size bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to str." - so even if they truncate, there's a NUL terminator. What's unsafe with that? Also, even if `int` is 64 bits long, `2^63 - 1` is still only `9 * 10^18`, so 19 bytes are enough for printing it, so are the 32 bytes I provided.

Comment: "What's unsafe with that?" - depends what you use the string value for. For example, if you use it as the directory for a chroot jail then you might "restrict" the process to too high a directory, giving it access to files it shouldn't. And just in general, it's often unsafe to use the wrong data or behave differently from what your function is documented to do. So you need to check for errors. If we accept your "also" argument, that your code is safe because the buffer is big enough, then sprintf would be equally safe. snprintf is "safer" only when the buffer might be too small.

Comment: @SteveJessop I see, and it's a valid argument. But I still don't think "12345678" is a valid Unix filesystem path.

Comment: heh, true. There are lots of general arguments about correct string handling, that don't apply in the specific case.

Comment: @SteveJessop Well, this case is one of them :)

Comment: quite, which is why in this case snprintf is not "safer". "Potentially better distributed when `int` is huge".

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is GCC:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char *ptr;
    int a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    a = rand();
    asprintf(&ptr, "%d", a);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    //DO SOMETHING
    free(ptr);
}
```